# How to use a custom pandas groupby aggregation function to combine rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with a `name` column and a `department` column. There are repeats in the `name` column that have different `department` values but all other column values are identical. I'd like to *flatten* these repeats into a single row and combine the different (unique) department values into a list. So, take first row of each group and just change the `department` value to a list of the unique `department` values in that group. So resulting dataframe should have exact same columns but no repeats in `name` column and `department` column now has lists of at least one element.

I thought to use `groupby` and a custom aggregation function passed to `agg()` but the following just totally fails. My thinking was that my aggregation function would get each group as a dataframe and if for each dataframe group I returned a series then the output of `groupby.agg(flatten_departments)` would be a dataframe.

```
def flatten_departments(name_group):
    #I thought name_group would be a df of that group 

    #this group is length 1 so this name doesn't actually repeat so just return same row
    if len(name_group) == 1:
        return name_group.squeeze() #turn length-1 df into a series to return, don't worry that department is a string and not a list for now
    else:
        #treat name_group like a df and get the unique departments
        departments = list(name_group['department'].unique())
        name_ser = name_group.iloc[0,:] #take first "row" of this group
        name_ser['department'] = departments #replace department value with list of unique values from group

        return name_ser

my_df = my_df.groupby(['name']).agg(flatten_departments)
```

This was a disaster and `name_group` is not a df but a series whose index is an index from the original df, and name is the name of some other column in the original df and value the value for that column.

I know that I could just do a for loop over the `groupby` object as follows

```
list_of_ser = []
for name, gp in my_df.groupby(['name']):
    if len(gp) == 1:
        list_of_ser.append(gp.squeeze())
    else:
        new_ser = gp.iloc[0,:]
        new_ser['department'] = list(gp['department'].unique())
        list_of_ser.append(new_ser)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_ser, columns=my_df.columns)
```

but I just thought that was the point of `agg`!

Any ideas how to accomplish my goal with `agg` or if the for loop is really the correct way. If the for loop is the right way, what is the point of `agg`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        name=list('ABCDEFGACEF'),
        dept=list('xyxyzxyzyxz')
    )
)

df.groupby('name').dept.apply(list).reset_index()
```

[image]

---

`agg` could have been used like this

```
df.groupby('name').dept.agg(dict(dept=lambda x: list(x))).reset_index()
```

---

if you need to preserve all other columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        name=list('ABCDEFGACEF'),
        dept=list('xyxyzxyzyxz')
    )
)

g = df.groupby('name')
pd.concat([g.dept.apply(list), g.first().drop('dept', 1)], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that one-line apply is completely boss. I also understand your `agg` example using the dictionary notation for it as in "do <dict value> for column <dict_key>". I guess what I'm still confused about is how do you use `agg` where the parameter is a function - what are the "rules" for that function in `agg`? Why is it being passed series for some other random column?!

Comment: see the `.dept` prior to the `.agg`.  That means that I've already limited the `agg` to a series.  That means that the `dict(dept=lambda)` is specifying that it will use the `lambda` and call the column `dept`.  Change the `dept` in that `dict` and you'lll have a different column name.  I'd not use `agg` in this case.  I just wanted to give you an example so you'd have a better idea what was going on.

Comment: the dataframe that comes out of your `apply` call only has `name` and `department` columns - how do I get the rest of the columns back too?